# Eclipse Java is finding "cannot be resolved" errors in comments?

Tags: java, eclipse

In the following code:

```
public void connect()
{
/*      
    String selectedPort = "COM1";
    String selectedPort = (String)window.cboxPorts.getSelectedItem();
    selectedPortIdentifier = (CommPortIdentifier)portMap.get(selectedPort);
*/ 
}
```

Eclipse complains that selectedPort cannot be resolved. Why is it even looking inside of a comment?

Comment: Save all files + Close it + Re-open (or re-build)

Comment: I think the solution was simply to do a refresh (F5) on your project.

Comment: Saving the files, closing and reopening the files, closing and reopening Eclipse did not help, but rebuilding (i.e. I hit run) ran it and cleared the errors!  Why does that work?

Comment: Very simple ,I hope you might have executed with existing  build changes so it would have shown you the errors, by rebuilding it applies new changes and execute fine

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to refresh the project.

Second, clean and rebuild. This must be happening as the new class file is not generated for you java file and eclipse is still looking at the previous compiled form.